# Convert regular CSS menu to dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation

I would like to convert the current CSS menu I have on m site to one with dropdown links. How would I go about doing this in the easiest way possible? My website is: [mycoincollection.net](http://mycoincollection.net)

Thanks!

Comment: Show your code, and what you have tried

Comment: P.S: on your website you're using jQuery code before you actually included the jQuery library - therefore the `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` error in console. (If you know what console is...)

Answer (score 0):

So you're using a jQuery script without including the jQuery library. That fixed it:

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/revija/3/edit?html,css,js,output)***

Here's also the fixed script with bugs removed:

```
$(function() {
  var pull = $('#pull'),
      menu = $('nav ul'),
      menuHeight = menu.height();

  pull.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    menu.slideToggle();
  });

  $(window).resize(function(){
    var w = $(this).width();
    if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
      menu.removeAttr('style');
    }
  }); 

});
```

(Note that if `pull` is already a jQuery Object `$('#pull')` there's no need to wrap it again into it like `$(pull).on(` - simply use `pull.on(`

So basically, before the closing `</body>` tag you should have first jQuery:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
```

and than your script

```
<script>
     /* your JS or jQuery code  here*/
</script>
```

and finally

```
</body>
```

Comment: But it closed right away so there's no time to click on anything in the mobile version. Thanks so much for putting up with me!

Comment: Ohh great than! I almost needed a coffee :)

Comment: You're still not done though ;) As I mentioned the menu closed as soon as I clicked on it on my phone. Thanks!!

Comment: Works fine now here too! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score -1):

This code will allow you to create an html dropdown.

```html
<form>

<input list="items" name="item">
<datalist id="items">
  <option value="Item 1">
  <option value="Item 2">
  <option value="Item 3">
  <option value="Item 4">
  <option value="Item 5">
</datalist>
</form>
```

Comment: I used @RokoC.Buljan's solution for my buggy JS. Now how do I add a dropdown menu? Thanks!!